# Bind DataList with multiple tables in dataset

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dataset, datalist

i have a Dataset with 4 tables , i m assigning this Dataset to datalist. i want to bind some fields from all tables in the datalist. Write now its only binding the Table which is on 0 index of dataset, on other table column name its giving exception.

How to bind the datalist with multiple table in dataset.?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `merge` the `DataTables` that are inside the `DataSet` and then bind to `datalist`

```
 DataTable dtblFinal = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataTable table in dataset.Tables)
    {
        dtblFinal.Merge(table, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    }
```